# How do you match partially complete floating numbers unambiguously?

Tags: antlr4

So, say we have a text of `2.at(0)` is there a way to tell antlr4 that 2. can't be a float with omitted trailing 0, unambiguously and without consuming the following token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to accept `2.` in `2. + 3` as a float, but not inside `2.at(0)` (or `2.   at(0)`), then no, that is not possible in ANTLR without some sort of predicate.

With a predicate, you'll need to add target specific code to your grammar that determines if a `.` is part of a float, or if it is a DOT token. For the Java target, that might look like this:

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

@header {
import java.util.*;
}

@members {
  private boolean nakedDotPartOfFloat() {

    // Start looking ahead 2 steps (1 step ahead id the '.')
    for (int i = 2; ; i++) {
      char nextChar = (char)_input.LA(i);

      if (Character.isSpaceChar(nextChar)) {
        // Ignore any space chars
        continue;
      }

      // If the character after the '.' is a letter, a float is not possible
      return !Character.isLetter(nextChar);
    }
  }
}

ADD
 : '+'
 ;

DOT
 : '.'
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+
 | [0-9]+ {nakedDotPartOfFloat()}? '.'
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

If you then tokenize the input `"2. 2.1 2.foo 2.+3"`, you'd get the following tokens:

```
9 tokens:
  1    FLOAT                          '2.'
  2    FLOAT                          '2.1'
  3    INT                            '2'
  4    DOT                            '.'
  5    ID                             'foo'
  6    FLOAT                          '2.'
  7    ADD                            '+'
  8    INT                            '3'
  9    EOF                            '<EOF>'
```

Comment: where do I find the documentation for the available classes like Character? Also, I tried LA(1) == EOF (at the end of input) and it also failed for some reason. Is there a trick?

Comment: Is there a standard way to add includes to generated files so taht predicates can use external functions and classes? (I am using it in the c++ development) I'd love to use stuff like cout for debugging predicates for example, but just sed'ing the files after each generation feels iffy

Comment: Character is a Java class and `_input` is a [`CharStream`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream.html). Including/importing other classes/dependencies can be done in the `@header { ... }` section of a grammar. Also see: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/dev/doc/cpp-target.md#named-actions

Comment: "failed for some reason"  without a more detailed explanation, no one can help you with that.